# custom WCF test client

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to build to build an application that has similar features to the WCF test client.
What I really need is the Test client's ability where you can enter the parameters. WCF's tool is very user-friendly that it can identify the type and allow you to select the type from the dropdown and works well with nested objects and arrays. 

I want a similar feature.
Is there a way to extract this functionality or perhaps is there another component with this functionality? - just so that I do not re-invent the wheel.
My target is that this is not only used for Web service communication but even for some other testing where it would call C# code directly.
What I need is the mechanism to enter parameters.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think all you need is a way to parse the WSDL so that you can detect parameter names and types, then the UI to allow data entry should not be too difficult. Check this WSDL parsing example here: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/06/simple-wsdl-object.html

Comment: Check out some links on how to discover and dynamically create WCF proxies: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx and http://wcfdynamicclient.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments Marc and Davide (+1).

Comment: But I would be more interested in the actual UI to all the data entry. I dont't think I explained myself clearly  - apologies.

Comment: the two approached are to extract the schema from the wsdl pr to work directly with the compiled proxy. for the former you would need as UI an Xml Grid. I'm not aware of a public nor a commercial component that does it. For the latter approach any property grid that uses reflection could work, winform has a PropertyGrid